# Polyline frequency to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, line

I have some animal tracking data in the form of a polyline shapefile and want to convert this to a raster so that each pixel is given a value of 1 for every instance in which a line crosses it. I've tried using Feature to Raster in ArcMap, with the Field specified to a field in which every line has a value of 1, but this only produces a raster with all pixels of "1" value, there is no consideration of the density of lines. I've also used Line Density, but this is taking into account lines within the *radius* of each pixel rather than only *within* the pixel.

Answer (score 1):

the workaround is to work in vector analysis.

You can create a [fishnet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) with squares of the size of your cells, then you use [spatial join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000)(with "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE" option) to get the count of the lines. At the end you can convert the vector grid to a raster.